# How to push a table onto the Lua stack

Tags: c, lua

Please explain, I need to put an analogue of this table on the Lua stack in C:

```
table_ = 
{
    param_1 = "Y1234",
    param_2 = "XXX",
    param_3 = "M"
}
```

I found the "lua_createtable" function:

[https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3... a_newtable](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_createtable)

```
void lua_createtable (lua_State *L, int narr, int nrec);
```

> Creates a new empty table and pushes it onto the stack. Parameter
> **narr** is a hint for how many elements the table will have as a sequence; parameter **nrec** is a hint for how many **OTHER** elements
> the table will have. Lua may use these hints to preallocate memory for
> the new table. This preallocation is useful for performance when you
> know in advance how many elements the table will have. Otherwise you
> can use the function lua_newtable.

I can’t understand - the parameters narr and nrec.

narr - how many elements will be in the table as a sequence. What is "as a sequence"? What's the sequence?

nrec - is a hint about how many OTHER elements will be in the table. What does others mean? What others ?

And it is not clear, after I create an empty table and it is marked on the stack, how can I fill this table with "key - value" values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From same [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7):

> A table with exactly one border is called a sequence. For instance, the table {10, 20, 30, 40, 50} is a sequence, as it has only one border (5). The table {10, 20, 30, nil, 50} has two borders (3 and 5), and therefore it is not a sequence. The table {nil, 20, 30, nil, nil, 60, nil} has three borders (0, 3, and 6), so it is not a sequence, too. The table {} is a sequence with border 0. Note that non-natural keys do not interfere with whether a table is a sequence.

As for filling that table, you use [`lua_setfield`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_setfield), so you can do something like this:

```c
lua_createtable(L, 0, 2);

lua_pushinteger(L, some_number_value);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "field_1");

lua_pushstring(L, some_string_value);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "field_2");
```